# PHP SCRIPT - not updating database when executed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been playing for quite a few hours, but to no avail, I have been building a script that will allow me to edit info on a webpage in the admin by editing it in a table. I used some tutorials etc, but now it just doesnt want to update the database.

I have three elements:

FIRST ONE: Table of listings - works fine

```
require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");


 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "cl52-abcdef","abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("cl52-abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 


$tbl_name="DealOne";
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>


<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Desc</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Dest</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>RRP</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Price Entry</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Entries Avail</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['holdesc1']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['holdest1']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['rrp1']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['cpe1']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['ea1']; ?></td>

<td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

Second One: where the form is to update the data

```
require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");


 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "cl52-abcdef","abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("cl52-abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 


$tbl_name="DealOne";


// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Desc</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Dest</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>RRP</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Price Entry</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Entries Avail</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><input name="desc" type="text" id="holdesc1" value="<? echo $rows['holdesc1']; ?>" size="35">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Destination" type="text" id="holdest1" value="<? echo $rows['holdest1']; ?>" size="35">
</td>
<td>
<input name="RRP" type="text" id="rrp1" value="<? echo $rows['rrp1']; ?>" size="8">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Price per Entry" type="text" id="cpe1" value="<? echo $rows['cpe1']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="Entries Available" type="text" id="ea1" value="<? echo $rows['ea1']; ?>" size="8">
</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

And finally the third one, that I believed would update the database, but it doesnt:

```
require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");


 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "cl52-abcdef","abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("cl52-abcdef") or die(mysql_error()); 


$tbl_name="DealOne";

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET holdesc1='$holdesc1', holdest1='$holdest1', rrp1='$rrp1', cpe1='$cpe1', ea1='$ea1' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='view_posts.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to get this to work? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: echo $sql; before calling mysql_query and verify that the string contains the values you think it should

Comment: Of course it doesnt works. You doesnt submit your form.$_POST?$id? Where your getting?

Comment: It comes up successful, but the data in the db has not been updated. Il have another look over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're rendering a single form to update multiple entries, all of which share attributes *with the same `id` HTML attribute*. Your update script can't distinguish between DOM elements with the same `id`, therefore, your records won't be updated correctly – even if you're identifying each entry by passing the `id` as a hidden attribute.

A possible solution would be to pass the entry's unique ID as part of each of that entry's attributes' `id`:

```
<input name="Price per Entry" type="text" id="cpe1_<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" value="<? echo $rows['cpe1']; ?>">
```

This creates distinct `id` elements for each form field. Then, in you update script, you can append the entry's `id` to the element `id` attribute so that it correctly associates the entry's attribute with the correct form field.

Answer (score 1):

Your $tbl_name isn't quoted.

You have

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET holdesc1='$holdesc1', holdest1='$holdest1', rrp1='$rrp1', cpe1='$cpe1', ea1='$ea1' WHERE id='$id'";
```

I believe it should be:

```
$sql="UPDATE '$tbl_name' SET holdesc1='$holdesc1', holdest1='$holdest1', rrp1='$rrp1', cpe1='$cpe1', ea1='$ea1' WHERE id='$id'";
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I have had a play and attacked it from a different angle! Ta